# Facebook C# SDK get user language/region

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the Facebook C# SDK. How can I get language of the user, so I can display all messages accordingly without forcing the user to choose his preferred language manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are developing a web app, then you can use `Accept-Language` Http header to detect the language

---

**EDIT 1**

For winforms application, you can use  `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` .

---

**EDIT2**

To get the `locale` using FB REST API :

```
dynamic fbResult = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/AngelaMerkel?access_token=AAABkECTD......").GetDynamicJsonObject();
Console.WriteLine(
    fbResult.locale ?? "-" + " > " +  //<----
    fbResult.location.country + " " + //<----
    fbResult.location.city + " " + //<----
    fbResult.name + " " + 
    fbResult.gender + " " + 
    fbResult.link + " " + 
    fbResult.updated_time);
```

You can find info about my extension method `GetDynamicJsonObject` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185869/c-sharp-returned-xml-to-class/8186377#8186377)

Comment: I know about the CurrentCulture, but I was hoping I could retrieve the user language as per Facebook registration info, or at least the country.

Comment: The above solution looks like what I'm looking for. Can you please advise, is there any way the same result can be accomplished using the C# SDK? Or alternatively, per the above example, how can I construct the right request URL - what else is required in addition to "access_token"? (I mean replacing the "......" placeholders).