# C# Returned .XML to class

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xml-parsing

I am tring to give an information from friendfeed API.

As you see in code, I am using an HttpRequest to get information. It's ok.

After that I am reading XML just fine with LINQ.

But now I create a "feed" class and I want to create an object for every returned value (i from finaltoclass).

How can I do this?

Can you help me with this?

Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        class feed { }
        public class entry {
            string body;
            string id;
            string url;

            public entry(string a, string b, string c)
            {
                body = a;
                id = b;
                url = c;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string username = "semihmasat";

            WebRequest ffreq = WebRequest.Create("http://friendfeed-api.com/v2/feed/" + username + "?format=xml");

            WebResponse ffresp = ffreq.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)ffresp).StatusDescription);
            Stream stream = ffresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string respfinal = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            XElement final = XElement.Load("http://friendfeed-api.com/v2/feed/" + username + "?format=xml");

            var finaltoclass = from i in final.Elements("entry")
                               select i;

            foreach (XElement i in finaltoclass) {
                string body= i.Element("body").Value;
                string id= i.Element("id").Value;
                string url= i.Element("url").Value;

                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", body, id, url);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think to read it this way (dynamic feed class - without declaring `feed`, `entry`, `via` and `from` classes ):

```
dynamic feed = new Uri("http://friendfeed-api.com/v2/feed/" + username + "?format=json").GetDynamicJsonObject();
foreach (var entry in feed.entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.from.name + "> " +  entry.body + " " + entry.url);
}
```

you will need [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and [this](http://pastebin.com/6b2fLChA) extension class

Comment: This is different from linq right ? ( json.net ) do i need linq to use this. Actualy i am new, now i have to decide what to learn.

Comment: No Its not linq.  All code you have to write is as above. No xml parsing, no class declaration.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. this look more usefull and easy. now i see a lot of we site api uses json. i dont need to learn linq by now. Thanks again :)

Comment: Thank you. and last think to ask those extension you gave the link ( not json.net ). what whould it do ?

Comment: Just add it to your project with copy&paste. It parses the json result using Json.Net and returns an `dynamic` object.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this code

```
 var finaltoclass = from i in final.Elements("entry")
    select new entry (i.Element("body").Value, i.Element("id").Value, i.Element("url").Value );
```

Comment: Nope, You will get IEnumerable<entry>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to an `ObservableCollection` of entry.